# Developing a game in Chromebook OS

Tags: unityscript

I’m trying to develop a game in my Chromebook OS. I can’t find any programming languages I can write in my Chromebook terminal. My terminal won’t take any new programming characters because every time I try to input a coding language in terminal the letters don’t show up. I also can’t find any game engines that support Chromebook OS. Do I have to resort to developing in the cloud with AWS. I tried that and I don’t understand it. I need Video Game Development team members to help me.

Comment: Why is this question tagged UnityScript, a language that Unity has not supported in the better part of a decade? From the way you've written this, it sounds like you're trying to program by typing code into a terminal prompt? Please tell me I've misunderstood, and you're using an [IDE](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=chromebook+ide&ia=web) or [code editor](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cheomebook+code+editor&ia=web).

Comment: Are you trying to use the console to install unity? A simple google (or search engine of your choice) will turn up a lot of help for that (https://chromeready.com/12655/install-use-unity-chromebook/).

Comment: In addition to Unity, web search brings up [Python / PyGame](https://www.bing.com/search?q=pygame+on+chromeos) & Google's [Android Studio](https://chromeos.dev/en/android-environment) as options.

Comment: If you're having difficulty with a specific engine / IDE, we might be able to help. To do that, you need to be specific enough that someone else can recreate your problem. For instance, list the steps you take for "input a coding language in terminal." Which language are you using? How did you verify the install? Are you using the compiler for the language or are you trying to code directly on the command line? Please edit (the link for that is under your post) to guide through the steps you took so that we can understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was trying to input the language C++ into the terminal. I don’t know how to use a compiler. I’m going to try program C++ into my other laptop a windows 10 laptop to create some simple games into it. I’ll let you know if I need more help. I’ll use Unity for that. I’ll be in touch with you to let you know if that works out.